# Python cachetools stats and use custom key

Tags: python, caching

I am looking for a way to use python's `cachetools` built-in library functionality of a cache, but also support hit/miss statistics, use a custom key function, and if possible support an unbounded cache?

Unfortunately, I could only find these ways:

1. If I want to use an unbound cache, and have hit/miss statistics:

   ```py
   from cachetools.func import lru_cache

   @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
   def foo(a, b, c=None):
       print("foo")
   ```
2. If I want to use an unbound cache, and use a custom key function:

   ```py
   from cachetools import cached

   @cached(
       cache={},
       key=lambda a, b, c=None: "a" if c is None else "b"
   )
   def foo(a, b, c=None):
       print("foo")
   ```

   or, use this "hack":

   ```py
   from cachetools import cached, LRUCache

   @cached(
       cache=LRUCache(maxsize=1, getsizeof=lambda _: 0), # will always pass the test of maxsize check
       key=lambda a, b, c=None: "a" if c is None else "b"
   )
   def foo(a, b, c=None):
       print("foo")
   ```

How would I go about if I want to use hit/miss statistics and a custom key function?
I know how to implement one on my own, I was just wondering if there is some already built-in way in python's cachetools/functools that supports this?